# iPhone - UIViewController not rotating when device orientation changes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have got my own custom UIViewController, which contains a UIScrollView with an UIImageView as it's subview.  I would like to make the image to auto rotate when device orientation changes, but it doesn't seem to be working...

In the header file, I've got;

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView   *containerView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
```

These components are initialised in the loadView function as below;

```
    containerView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://..."]];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [image release];

    [containerView addSubview:imageView];
```

And I have added the following method, assuming that's all I need to make the view auto-rotate...

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

MyViewController loads fine with the image I've specified to grab from the URL, and the shouldAutorotate... function is being called, with the correct UIInterfaceOrientation, when I flip the device too.

However, didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method do not get called, and the image doesn't seem to rotate itself...
Could someone please point out what I need to add, or what I have done wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 25):

This may not be the right answer for you, because you don't specify the context that the UIViewController's in, but I just found an important gotcha in the Apple documentation that explains the similar problem I'm having.

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait
>   orientation by default and do not
>   rotate to a landscape orientation
>   unless all of the root view
>   controllers support such an
>   orientation. When a device orientation
>   change occurs, the tab bar controller
>   queries its array of view controllers.
>   **If any one of them does not support
>   the orientation, the tab bar
>   controller does not change its
>   orientation.**

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed that there are issues when rotating a UIView that's not the first or only view as a direct child of the main window.

So if your UIView is part of a Navigation Controller or a Tab View Controller, you'll also need to override shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation on the Navigation Controller or Tab View Controller.

Also: using `[UIApplication setStatusBarOrientation]` helps to work around things if/when you need to do it manually.

Comment: Yes, my custom View Controller that has the ImageView I want to rotate is indeed sitting on top of a Tab View Controller.  
I will give that a try! Thanks Ed :)

Comment: Thanks Ed.
I have implemented my custom UITabViewController & UINavigationController and it now works just fine. 
Just as you mentioned :) 

I also need to make some of the views to stay in the Portrait orientation at all the time so I will work on that next!

Answer (score 1):

To make this kind of thing work in my application, I had to override

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

and also layoutSubviews

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews called");

    ...recalc rects etc based on the new self.view.bounds...
}
```

I'm not sure that this is absolutely required, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response frankodwyer :)
I will try overriding the didRotate delegate method you've mentioned.

Comment: Hi frankodwyer,

OK, I have encountered a major issue.
Neither of these delegate methods are being called;

        willRotateToInterfaceOrientation
        didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

Is there something I need to setup in order for these methods to be called and rotate properly?

Comment: I just added the methods to my ViewController.m, nothing else. I checked, and both methods get called. (p.s. it is better to put followups in comments than post them as an answer to the main question - though it is a pain to put code in comments. Or you can add further info by editing your q.)

Comment: Thanks for the advise :) I've only signed up for it so bare with me for now... 
I will try implementing a simpler ViewController object with just an ImageView and see how it goes. 
Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: one thing that occurs to me, is you should make sure your view is wired up in Interface builder correctly (i.e. that it really is the view on the screen, or a subview of it)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, if you add a subview to a view, it's your responsibility to make sure that the methods are passed to the subview; a couple of days ago I wrote a [short post](http://davidebenini.it/2009/01/03/viewwillappear-not-being-called-inside-a-uinavigationcontroller/) about this. For example, if you have a `UIViewController` and add a `UINavigationController` as subview, you must add this code to the `UIViewController` if you want `viewWillAppear:animated:` to be called when `UINavigationController.view` appears:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[projectNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

It might be the case that the  `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` and   `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method also need to be called by the superview; I am not really sure about this, but give it a try.

Comment: This does sound similar to my UIImageView issue... 
The super view of my custom View Controller is the Tab View Controller, so it sorta makes complement to what Ed pointed out earlier as well. Thanks nutsmuggler :)

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in [Apple Technical Q&A QA1688](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1688.html).

Sometimes if you stack multiple views on top of each other **for some reason**, the anotherController might not receive rotation event.

```
[myWindow addSubview:primaryViewController.view];
[myWindow addSubview:anotherController.view];
```

A lazy way (not a good design) to fix this is only add one subview on window, but initialize multiple controller on the app delegate. Then when you need to switch window, remove the current view and add the view you want

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
AppDelegate *dg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[[dg window] addSubview:[[dg viewController] view]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied this from [this link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8030653)

And it works for me.... Reason why i have added this here is to make it easy for others to find. It took me many hours to find this fix:

Make a new set of class files of the UIViewController type, go into the .h file of this class and change this line

```
@implementation MyTabBarController: UIViewController {}
@end
```

to something like this

```
@implementation MyTabBarController: UITabBarController{

}
```

Now go into the nib file and click on the UITabBarController object and go to it's identity tab, and make it Class MyTabBarController.

now in MyTabBarController.m make sure this is in it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)io {
     return YES;
}
```

You can probably get rid of everything else in there if you want.

Comment: Sorry but you haven't answered his question at all! He clearly states that he already has that line of code!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this having a similar problem. I have a series of view controllers/complex views, that all rotate perfectly and couldn't figure out why the new one I just added on wasn't rotating. After a LOT of trial and error, the reason was that I wasn't calling the init method (it's the standard init method) when allocating the view controller; 
e.g. I was doing

```
    m_timerViewController = [TimerViewController alloc];
```

instead of

```
    m_timerViewController = [[TimerViewController alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on jonoogle's post. I had a similar error. My view has a nib and my custom init:

```
- (id)initWithCategory:(Category *)category inManagedObjectContext:context{
```

didn't include the call to init the nib.

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Adding that line made my view rotate like it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

just do this if you what to rotate from landscape to portrait!

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```